# I can't scroll to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

You see, for some reasons some times I can't scroll to the bottom of the page (some times it happens in the middle too). Here is a screenshot:

[image]
Why does this happen? I can't create a jsfiddle, because I can't reproduce it since sometimes when I reload I have this problem, sometimes it works fine... It happens in a random way. I have no idea what might be causing this. It just stops scrolling before reaching the bottom. I know this might be classified as an open question but I just want to see, if anyone have had this problem. Any suggestions are appreciated..

**UPDATED**
Ok, here is the code I used to style the scrollbar and the scrolling, in CSS:

```
body 
{
    scrollbar-face-color: rgb(0,131,168);
    scrollbar-track-color: rgba(0,131,168,0.8);
    scrollbar-arrow-color: rgba(0,131,168,0.5);
    scrollbar-shadow-color: rgb(0,131,168);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track 
{
    background-color: rgba(0,131,168,0.5);
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
    width: 5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb 
{
    background-color: rgb(0,131,168);
}
```

in the javascript, "vista" is the main container, I wrote:

```
    var vistaProfesional = document.getElementById('vista');
    vistaProfesional.style.overflow = "auto";
    vistaProfesional.style.overflowX = "hidden";
    vistaProfesional.style.height = 100 + '%';
```

I have been thinking, and I found out that, when I was doing the whole thing, I wanted it to have a smooth scroll, therefore I used the [smoothWheel plugin](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/jquery.smoothwheel) because it is easy to use and since I am new to programming this seems a charm. However, right after the code abode I wrote:

```
 $("#vista").smoothWheel();
```

to initialize it and though it works, it is when this plugin is active that I have this issue. If I comment that line of code and stay with the normal scroll, the problem described doesn't occur. As for one of the comments, yes, the zoom is already in 100%

Comment: A screenshot does not provide enough information to diagnose this problem. Try creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we have something to go on. (Though in creating the example you may solve the problem yourself.)

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce it in more than one browser?

Comment: You would have to post some code, because it has to be in your CSS or JS... how do you suppose anyone even starts tackling this problem, only seeing an image?

Comment: Is that a custom scroll bar, eg javascript based, or just a styled one?

Comment: it was just CSS style

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem in several websites before. Set your zoom level to 100% to allow you to scroll to the bottom of the page.

Often when the zoom is  not equal to 100% there is a partial row that is not shown, so the website thinks that you have not displayed the bottom of the page, so won't fetch the rest, or update the scroll bar properly.

Comment: I is 100% I think it has something to do with the plugin I mention in the update

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify height to `body` and `html` because as for as i know **Scrolling plugins** need that, so

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

If this does'nt solve your issue you may use **[Nice Scrolling Plugin](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/)** which has a lot of properties, also it has been **documented** very well.

Hope this helps you.